# Jmeter plugin execution throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, linux, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I've looked for answers to this problem, but couldn't find any over the internet. Maybe someone here ran into this issue before.

I have a CentOS machine with **Jmeter 3.1**. On this machine everything works fine. I created a new VM, and **copied** the jmeter directory to the new machine with everything set up. Test execution *works fine*, but when I try to use any of the plugins (*cmdrunner-2.0.jar or by JMeterPluginsCMD.sh*) 
I get an 
**Exception** back, with not much information what's wrong:

```
[root@box bin]# java -jar "/opt/apache-jmeter-3.1/lib/cmdrunner-2.0.jar" -n --tool Reporter  --input-jtl "/tmp/data.csv" --plugin-type SynthesisReport --generate-csv "/tmp/report.csv"
WARN    2017-10-22 12:41:57.204 [jmeter.u] (): Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'sampleresult.default.encoding', defaulting to:ISO-8859-1
WARN    2017-10-22 12:41:57.224 [jmeter.u] (): Exception 'null' occurred when fetching String property:'jmeterPlugin.prefixPlugins'
INFO    2017-10-22 12:41:57.224 [kg.apc.j] (): Using JMeterPluginsCMD v. N/A
INFO    2017-10-22 12:41:57.229 [jmeter.u] (): Setting Locale to en_US
INFO    2017-10-22 12:41:57.238 [kg.apc.j] (): Loading user properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/user.properties
INFO    2017-10-22 12:41:57.238 [kg.apc.j] (): Loading system properties from: /opt/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/system.properties
ERROR: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
*** Problem's technical details go below ***
Home directory was detected as: /opt/apache-jmeter-3.1/lib
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getStrikeForSlot(CompositeStrike.java:75)
        at sun.font.CompositeStrike.getFontMetrics(CompositeStrike.java:93)
        at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:359)
...
...
```

> ERROR: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

That's all I get. The only differences between the two machines is:

Working platform:

**kernel** 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64
**java** (build 1.8.0_131-b12)

Not working:

**kernel**  3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64, 
**java** (build 1.8.0_144-b01)

There are no environment variables missing.

*Any suggestions are more than welcomed*

Comment: @user7294900 I'm running on a linux machine with no UI, so I can't check this. I have tried to download the plugin again from jmeter website, and replace it with the one I have, but the problem consists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a java bug on this particular platform:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1484079

Comment: That's why it made no sense. It works on one machine but not on the other, with a slightly newer java version.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe it - **yum update java** solved my issue. The thing is, I just updated java last week..